# Repeat THEAD on each PDF page, using convertApi

Tags: html, convertapi

I would like to convert a large TABLE in PDF with a THEAD and TFOOT. A cannot have a good result with a THEAD part. 
In the PDF, after the first page, the TR are under the THEAD block.

Someone have the same problem (and find a solution) ?

Do I use a specific CSS rules or declaration of HTML ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put these in a  tag or tour CSS document:

```
thead { display: table-header-group }
tfoot { display: table-row-group }
tr { page-break-inside: avoid }
```